# Карточные масти

Tags: этимология

Задумалась: а каково происхождение названий карточных мастей? С пиками и червами (видимо, от слова "червонный") более-менее все понятно, а вот почему "трефы" (или все-таки "трефи"?) и "бубны"? А также почему "туз" и "валет"?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Треф**ы** - от фр. trèfle 'клевер'; в простонародье - *крести* (у В.И. Даля - крестЫ). Что касается масти **бубны**, то название родственно наименованию музыкального инструмента (бубен). Налицо противоречие: масть эта изображается в виде ромбов, нет и намека на ударный инструмент. Но на старинных немецких картах, которые стали проникать в Россию через страны Восточной Европы в XVII веке, бубновая масть изображалась в виде звоночков, бубенчиков. В России в 17-18 вв. эта масть так и называлась - *звонки, боти*. Этимологически название *бубны* является калькой с немецкого Schellen 'звонки' через чешское bubny. Очень редко употреблялось название этой масти, заимствованное из французского Carreau (каро) — 'квадратики, клетки'. Интересно, что в дореволюционной России заключённые носили на одежде знак в виде чёрного ромба, который в обиходе назывался *бубновый туз*. Отсюда слово «забубённый».

Название карты **ТУЗ** пришло в русский язык через польск. tuz из ср.-в.-нем. tu^s, du^s "туз", которое происходит из ю.-франц. daus, франц. dеuх, народнолат. duЎs "два, двойка".

**Валет** от фр. valet, «слуга», «лакей», этимологически уменьшительное от «вассал»; старое русское название «холоп», «хлап».

Вообще тема происхождения названий игральных карт, их мастей в разных языках очень широкая и заманчивая. Пока искала информацию, тыщу раз отвлекалась на всякие факты. Было интересно. Спасибо за вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Имеет место следующее мнение по данному вопросу

Треф -

en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treif

www.eleven.co.il/article/14155

Козырь -

ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%88%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82

www.eleven.co.il/article/12034

Туз - по-немецки "Daus", может переводиться как "дьявол". В немецкой колоде и карта соответствующая есть

dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1060038/%D0%A2%D0%A3%D0%97

de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daus_(Spielkarte)

Comment: Информация по ссылкам, тем более Википедии, может изменится, поэтому публикуйте выдержки и при необходимости давайте ссылку.

Comment: Особенно по темам, весьма смутное отношение к русскому языку имеющим.